# Matrix $A$ with characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

> Given: Matrix $A$ with characteristic polynomial $p(x) = (x+3)^2(x-1)(x-5)$
>
> Also given: $\rho(A+2I) + \rho(A+3I) + \rho(A-5I) = 9$ (btw $\rho$ means rank of the matrix)
>
> Prove: $A$ is diagonalizable.

I tried by saying first the the eigenvalues are $-3,1,5.$

Then, I know that their algebraic multiplicity of $-3$ is $2$, of $1$ is $1$, and of $5$ is $1$.

Now I need **only** to prove that the geometric multiplicity of $-3 $ is $2$ to show that $A$ is diagonalizable.

How can I prove it by using $\rho(A+2I) + \rho(A+3I) + \rho(A-5I) = 9$ ?

Comment: You know the rank of $A+2I$ and of $A-5I$. From that, compute that the rank of $A+3I$ is $2$.

Comment: I know that A's rank has to be 4 because the sum of the algebric multiplexing is 4. and also that A is singular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You know $$\rho(A-5I)=4-1=3$$  (why ?) and that $$\rho(A+2I)=4$$
(why ?)

What do you conclude from that, given the work you already did ?

Comment: Is it true that $\rho(A-5I)$ = 1 ? If yes, is it because its algebric multiplexing is 1?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS - Yes. This would imply that the geometric multiplexing is $\leq 1$. But you also know that it is at least $1$ since it is an eigenvalue and so the geometric multiplexing is $1$

Comment: And another last thing, How did you know that "n" is 4? I mean, Is it because the sum of the algebric multiplexing is 4? (2+1+1)?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS - By the way, do you study for the "Algebra aleph" exam ?

Comment: Yes, I do. Unfortunately..

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS - No, I deduced that because the dimension of the matrix is the same of the degree of the characteristic polynomial

Comment: Exactly. which means 2+1+1 = 4

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS - Good luck! Its a great course in my opinion

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS - oh yes, your'e right

Comment: Yeah, but books sucks. Alright, no time to waste, I'm back to more questions.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS - What book are you using ?

Comment: Israel's Open university books of Linear Algebra I.

Comment: If you've more time: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833982/t-m-2x2r-rightarrow-m-2x2r-linear-map