# $T: M_{2\times 2}(R) \rightarrow M_{2 \times 2}(R)$ linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

Given: $T: M_{2\times 2}(R) \rightarrow M_{2 \times 2}(R)$ is linear transformation.

Also $T(X) =$ $
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
X + X        
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$ 
For every $X$ in $M_{2 \times 2}(R)$

Find base for $\ker T$ and $Im T$.

It;s pretty straight forward that $\ker T = Sp
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        -1 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$ 
 (For every $a,b,c,d$)

How can I compute $ImT$? Do I need to find ANY 3 vectors  in $\mathbb{R}^4$ which are linearly independent and that if I put them in $(a+b+c, 2b+d, d,d)$ they aren't sent to $(0,0,0,0)$ like $(1,0,-1,0)$?

Comment: I thought the already provided answer was adequate. And your computation of the linear map is correct. But anyway, the image is spanned by the vectors you obtain by choosing $(a,b,c,d)$ in the standard basis, so it is spanned by the rows of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\1&2&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$. If you omit the duplicate vector, you see that the remaining ones are independent, hence a basis. (Barring mistakes.)

Comment: Still didn't understand how to get those 4 vectors. @Andreas Caranti. Sorry for my rudeness, I'm on low carb diet.

Comment: Choose $(a,b,c,d) = (1,0,0,0)$, then $(a,b,c,d) = (0,1,0,0)$, then $(a,b,c,d) = (0,0,1,0)$, then $(a,b,c,d) = (0,0,0,1)$.

Comment: Yup, I figured it out by myself a second ago after you mentioned I need to choose a base to represent $ImT$. Thanks!

Comment: As to *sarcasm*, I used to resent it as a young man, now that I'm older I simply think the problem is with the utterer.

Comment: That's happenning to me alot. I just don't care about anything. I don't care if someone dies, I don't care if someone laughs at me. I don't care about myself actually too, although I have working to become a better version of myself everyday by working out 5 times a week, eating a strict diet 6 times a week (the 7th day I cheat with 1 meal out of 6 so it's pretty much still strict by about 98% of the time {41/42 meals}) and studying to a first degree while serving in the military because I'm obeyed to serve here in Israel for 3 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $T:V\to W$ is a linear transformation and you have it clearly
defined on every element of $V$.

Choose a basis for $V$ and compute the representing matrix of $T$
with respect to the chosen basis.

Comment: Well, I'm having difficulties defining that base for every $X$ in $M_{2x2}(R)$. can I say that it's just$ T(a b c d) = (a+b+c,2b+d,d,d)$ (in a matrix form) and thus I can take 3 vectors in $R^4$ that are linearly independent and say that they form a basis of $ImT$?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS  use the standard basis (all entries are 0 except for one entry which is 1). Work with 4 dimensional coordinate vectors to represent an element of V